# Strange behavior in bluetooth device discovery with 32feet library

Tags: c#, winforms, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, 32feet

i'm trying to discover bluetooth devices with the 32feet library for c#. I wrote a little test application to discover and later pair devices. And I recognised a strange behavior.

This is how I start the discovery:

```
BluetoothComponent bc = new BluetoothComponent(new BluetoothClient());

bc.DiscoverDevicesProgress += Bc_DiscoverDevicesProgress;
bc.DiscoverDevicesComplete += Bc_DiscoverDevicesComplete;

bc.DiscoverDevicesAsync(255, true, true, true, false, null);
```

So, nothing new here.

At this time running the test, I'm only able to find successfully paired devices and phones (tested with samsung and apple). When I'm starting the windows built-in bluetooth discovery service in **parallel** I'm able to see all devices in my test application.

I've also tried to set the radio mode to discoverable, but this had no effect at all.

Do I miss some setting here?

Thanks in advance